# Format datetime from string "20151210T11:25:11123"

Tags: c#

I have string format **"20151210T11:25:11123"**, can't convert to type `DateTime` in C# help me?

```
string date = "20151210T11:25:11123";
DateTime datea = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a time of `20151210T11:25:11123` but telling it to parse it as if it were formatted as `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt`. The format does not match the string, so you get a FormatException.  You need to provide a format that matches the string you have.  It isn't clear to me what the last 5 digits are but a format like `yyyyMMddThh:mm:ssfff` will parse the string as `12/10/2015 11:25:11 AM`.  You may need to adjust the last part of the format to match whatever is actually encoded there in your string.

```
string date = "20151210T11:25:11123";
DateTime datea = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMddThh:mm:ssfff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Console.WriteLine(datea); // 12/10/2015 11:25:11 AM
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont know who was down voted in my answer, but i think is because our answers are similar, so you answered before me, but when you answered I'm have already write my answer, just for this I post, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

with value datetime string ="20160121T13:26:24090"

code error :

DateTime datea = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMddThh:mm:ssfff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Console.WriteLine(datea); // 12/10/2015 11:25:11 AM